# Java iText Page X of Y

Tags: java, itext

I’m using iText to generate a PDF document in my Java EE application. Coding for the PDF file is reside in a JSP.

I want to achieve the following page formatting in my each page footer,

---

REF: XXXXXXX                                                            Page X of Y

---

How can I get Page X of Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample here: http://faq.javaranch.com/java/ItextExample

In a nutshell, you create a Header/Footer class with an onPageEnd event to add a header or footer.

Addendum from my comment below after reading the other question from OP:
PdfWriter.getCurrentPageNumber only returns the current page number. You can't get the total while writing the document because, obviously, you don't know the total yet. The way to do that is explained here: [How to add the total page number on each page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759909/how-to-add-total-page-number-on-every-page-with-itext) or in Ashis' answer here.

Comment: You apparently found a sample already as you asked a more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923363/java-itext-footer

Comment: This is not a solution for getting the Y in X of Y.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt you're right, PdfWriter.getCurrentPageNumber only returns the current page number. You can't get the total while writing the document because, obviously, you don't know the total yet. The way to do that is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759909/how-to-add-total-page-number-on-every-page-with-itext
Or Ashis' answer.