# Java iText Footer

Tags: java, itext

I’m trying to generate a PDF using a JSP page and my coding outline as follows,

```
Document document           = new Document(PageSize.A4,70/*Left*/,70/*Right*/,140/*Top*/,30/*Bottom*/);

response.setContentType("application/pdf" );
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=vishwa-mandate.pdf");

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
document.open();

HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("This is page "), true);
document.setFooter(footer);

/* PAGE 01 */

document.newPage(); 

/* PAGE 02 + */

document.close();
```

Page footer doesn’t apply to PAGE 01 once I explicitly call `document.newPage();`
How can I get the footer though out the whole document?

Comment: HeaderFooter is one of your classes with onPageEnd() right ? Can you please provide its source code ?

Comment: I have been able to fix the problem. The mistake that I have done was, I have called the document.setFooter(footer) method after opening the document. But when I set the footer before opening the document problem was solved. Thanks for your enthusiasm in order to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setFooter(footer) should be called before opening the document

Corrected code as follows

```
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("This is page "), true);
document.setFooter(footer);

// Document should open after setting the footer
document.open();
```