# Netsuite PDF Templating: get number of pages as attribute

Tags: pdf, freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I am templating pdfs in Netsuite using freemarker and I want to display the footer only on the last page. I have been doing some research, but couldn't find a solution (since looks like the environment does not allow me to include or import libs), so I thought that just comparing the number of the page with the total pages in an if tag would be a nice and easy workaround. I already know how to display the numbers by using the `<pagenumber/>` and `<totalpages/>` tags, but still cannot get them as values so I can use them like this:

```
<#if (pagenumber == totalpages) >
    ... footer html...
</#if>
```

Any ideas of how or where can I get those values from?

Comment: Already try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670704/freemarker-pdf-header-footer-and-page-breaks, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are trying won't work, because you are mixing BFO and Freemarker syntax. Netsuite uses two different "engines" to process PDF Templates. The first step is Freemarker, which merges the record fields with your template and produces an XML file, which is then converted by BFO into a PDF file. The `<totalpages/>` element is meaningless to Freemarker, as it is only converted into a number by BFO later.

Unfortunately, the ability to add a footer to only the last page of a document is currently a limitation of BFO, as per the [BFO FAQ](http://bfo.com/faq.jsp#3.18):

> At the moment we do not have a facility for explicitly assigning a
>   footer or header to the last page in a document when the number of
>   pages is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN add it after a page break - and put the page break at the end of the body

```
<pbr footer="nlfooter" footer-height="25%"></pbr>
</body>
```

The issue here is - on a one page output - you will get 2 pages minimum...  it will always ADD a page for the disclaimer / footer...