# How to get count of pages

Tags: java, itext

in iText i only need to get one number: Count of all pages in document.

I have this class what i get as a pattern somewhere from iText:

```
class PageCounter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    PdfTemplate t;
    Image total;

    @Override
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        t = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);

        try {
            total = Image.getInstance(t);
            total.setRole(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[] { 24, 24, 2 });
            table.setTotalWidth(tableWidth);

            Font font = returnCustomFont(fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
                    BaseColor.BLACK);

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy / HH:mm");
            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(
                    new Phrase(dateFormat.format(new Date()), font));
            cell1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
            cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell1.setFixedHeight(30);
            table.addCell(cell1);

            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()), font));
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            cell2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell2.setFixedHeight(30);
            cell2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
            table.addCell(cell2);

            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(total);
            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell3.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
            table.addCell(cell3);

            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 30, 40, canvas);
            canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(t, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber())), 2, 2, 0);
    }
}
```

The trouble is, that it derives count of all pages only as Image format, and i need it as anything formattable as text (Integer, String etc.).

The only one thing I have found is this question in stackoverflow:
[How to add total page number on every page with iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759909/how-to-add-total-page-number-on-every-page-with-itext)

And the very first answer is interesting, but unfortunatelly, there is no example, only this description (inbetween lines):

---

1) Process the output from a PdfWriter to a bytestream first with a dummy page count.

2) Create a PdfReader from that bytestream, calling PdfReader.getNumberOfPages to get the actual page count.

3) Recreate the PDF output, knowing what the page count will be, changing the footer accordingly.

---

If nobody had any better plan how to achieve that page count, I would be interested, how specifically can i handle POINT NUMBER 1.
Do you have any idea?

NOTE: When i start to type number of current page, i already need to know count of all pages and type it there too.

My WHOLE code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Pdf1formiText {

public static final String DEST = "c:/radek-folder/pdf1iText.pdf";
protected int horizontalAlignmentLeft = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
protected int horizontalAlignmentCenter = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
protected int verticalAlignmentMiddle = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
protected int verticalAlignmentTop = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
protected String fontTypeRegular = "c:/radek-folder/font_sitebook.ttf";
protected String fontTypeBold = "c:/radek-folder/font_sitebook_bold.ttf";
protected float fontSizeRegular = 10f;
protected float fontSizeLarger = 14f;
protected float fontSizeLarge = 16f;
float tableWidth;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new Pdf1formiText().createPdf(DEST);
    System.out.println("done");
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    float[] columns = { 100, 50, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 50 };
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 36, 36, 36, 36);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    writer.setPageEvent(new PageCounter());

    document.open();
    PdfPCell cell;
    // Header part
    PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    mainTable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(0);
    mainTable.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    mainTable.setTotalWidth(columns);
    mainTable.setLockedWidth(true);

    PdfPTable subTable1 = new PdfPTable(columns.length);
    subTable1.setTotalWidth(columns);
    subTable1.setLockedWidth(true);
    cell = createAndReturnTextCell(horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Přenosové trasy GTS", columns.length, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeLarge,
            BaseColor.BLACK);
    cell.setPaddingTop(10f);
    cell.setPaddingBottom(15f);
    subTable1.addCell(cell);

    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Trasa [-]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Pásmo [GHz]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Kap a konf [Mbit/s]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Typ zařízení Index [-]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Zeměpis.délka WGS84[°-'-\"]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Zeměpis.šířka WGS84[°-'-\"]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Nadm.výška [m]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Výška ant.[m]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Průměr ant./zisk [m]/[dB]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Útlum vlnovod [dB]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Výkon vysílač dBm", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable1, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Délka trasy [m]", 1, 1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    mainTable.addCell(subTable1);

    PdfPTable subTable2 = new PdfPTable(columns.length);
    subTable2.setTotalWidth(columns);
    subTable2.setLockedWidth(true);
    addTableCellToTable(subTable2, innerTableInCell1(), 10, 1);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable2, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "2959.32", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable2, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "2009-03-30", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    mainTable.addCell(subTable2);

    PdfPTable subTable3 = new PdfPTable(columns.length);
    subTable3.setTotalWidth(columns);
    subTable3.setLockedWidth(true);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "CZ5142", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "100M", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "QAM_32", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "28", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "FibeAir 1500p 38GHz", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "N/A", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Praha 4 Milevská 7", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
            PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "14°26'18''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "14°26'18''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "265", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(subTable3, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "70", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    mainTable.addCell(subTable3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        PdfPTable subTable4 = new PdfPTable(columns.length);
        subTable4.setTotalWidth(columns);
        subTable4.setLockedWidth(true);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "CZ5142", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "100M", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "QAM_32", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "28", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "FibeAir 1500p 38GHz", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
                PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "N/A", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "Praha 4 Milevská 7", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
                PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "14°26'18''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
                PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "14°26'18''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular,
                PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "265", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        addTextCellToTable(subTable4, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
                "70", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        mainTable.addCell(subTable4);
    }

    document.add(mainTable);
    document.close();
}

private PdfPTable innerTableInCell1() throws DocumentException {
    int[] columnWidths = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    PdfPTable innertable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths.length);
    innertable.setWidths(columnWidths);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "Brno Špitálka 8 Brno Hájecká 1068/14 CZ5159", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular,
            fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "38510.5", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "37250.5", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "MINI-LINK/E 38GHz", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "V / 4x2M / 1+0", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "16?37'21.4''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "16?38'16.94''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "49?11'47.3''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "49?10'18.75''", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "217", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "201", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "92", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "10", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "0.30/40.4", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "0.60/44.3", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "UKY21008/SC11", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "UKY21009/SC11", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "0", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "0", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "15", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    addTextCellToTable(innertable, horizontalAlignmentCenter, verticalAlignmentMiddle,
            "15", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular, PdfPCell.BOX);
    return innertable;
}

private static void addTableCellToTable(PdfPTable mainTable, PdfPTable insertedTable, int colspan,
        int rowspan) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(insertedTable);
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    mainTable.addCell(cell);
}

private static void addTextCellToTable(PdfPTable table, int horizontalAlignment,
        int verticalAlignment, String value, int colspan, int rowspan,
        String fontType, float fontSize, int borderStyle) {
    BaseFont base = null;
    try {
        base = BaseFont.createFont(fontType, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Font font = new Font(base, fontSize);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
    cell.setBorder(borderStyle);
    table.addCell(cell);
}

private static PdfPCell createAndReturnTextCell(int horizontalAlignment,
        int verticalAlignment, String value, int colspan, int rowspan,
        String fontType, float fontSize, BaseColor color) {
    BaseFont base = null;
    try {
        base = BaseFont.createFont(fontType, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Font font = new Font(base, fontSize);
    font.setColor(color);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}

private static void addImageCellToTable(PdfPTable table, int horizontalAlignment,
        int verticalAlignment, Image value, int colspan, int rowspan, String fontType,
        float fontSize) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(value);
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell(cell);
}

class PageCounter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    PdfTemplate t;
    Image total;

    @Override
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        t = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
        t.setColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        try {
            total = Image.getInstance(t);
            total.setRole(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[] { 48, 2 });
            table.setTotalWidth(tableWidth);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);

            PdfPCell cell = createAndReturnTextCell(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                    verticalAlignmentTop,
                    String.format("%d /", writer.getPageNumber()), 1, 1,
                    fontTypeRegular, 13f, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
            cell.setFixedHeight(30);
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);

            addImageCellToTable(table, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, verticalAlignmentTop,
                    total, 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, 40, canvas);
            canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(t, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber())), 1, 1, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you need the number of pages of  document that's been created already, or are you creating a document and do you need to know the current number of pages?
Also: 
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext5
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext7

Comment: that document does not exist as a file in the moment when i need to use this code. I have added my whole code for sure.

Comment: When exactly do you need the number? While you are still creating the document? When you've just finished adding the last piece of content?

Comment: Whats the problem on asking the PdfWriter instance about the .getPageNumber() at any time in the creation process?

Comment: Have a look into class PageCounter / onOpenDocument method. That "Image total" brings the picture with the number of page.
When it starts creating document, it is already capable to find out that count. And i only need it in different format than Image.

Comment: COeDev : Problem is that i need the count after opening document (class PageCounter / onOpenDocument method). When i start to type number of current page, i already need to know count of all pages and type it there too.

Comment: @user7968180 *"Have a look into class PageCounter / onOpenDocument method. That "Image total" brings the picture with the number of page. When it starts creating document, it is already capable to find out that count."* - That is wrong: The "image total" start out as an empty canvas a reference to which is added to each page. Just shortly before closing the document, in `onCloseDocument`, the actual number of pages is written to that empty canvas.

Comment: Ok, but i am waching it and still dont know how to get it from that PdfTemplate variable. Or derive it from anything else.